# Email Notification unpredicted behaviour in sonarqube

Tags: plugins, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

This is about sonarqube 5.1 version

I have issue assign plugin and also subscribed to the emails in my profile page. I've done some erroneous SVN commits deliberately to check the email notification settings but it doesn't seem to work correctly. I receive emails sometimes but other times it doesn't work like that.

I know this is not a constructive enough question but I'm really stucked here after trying all the scenarios and going through the documentation.
Any insight would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should uninstall this plugin. It is compatible, but it does not work correctly. The problem is that [SonarQube 5.1](http://jira.sonarsource.com/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?version=11627&styleName=Html&projectId=10930) introduced core auto assignment (see [automatic issue assignment](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Automatic+Issue+Assignment) and [SONAR-5906](http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-5906)). The core functionality & plugin execution order is as follows:

1. Plugin during the execution assigns issues & collects information to whom he should send e-mails. Next core functionality reassign issues.
2. Core functionality reassigns issues
3. Plugin sends emails with incorrect data

See [topic on SonarQube mailing list](http://sonarqube-archive.15.x6.nabble.com/SQ-5-1-How-to-disable-automatic-issues-assignment-td5034866.html)

Comment: Thank you very much. Just to clarify. core feature also send emails after auto assigning right?

Comment: Unfortunately not. You have only 4 basic notification types: `Changes in issues assigned to me or reported by me` (only changes to the currently assigned, not new), `Issues resolved as false positive or won't fix`, `New issues` (not many information, but see [SONAR-6045](http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6045)), `New quality gate status`.

Comment: hi, need further help buddy, @agabrys. I deliberately made a sonar error and commited through SVN. All of the registered members got an email. But it was a generic one. Sonar has not assigned the error to anybody. Have any idea why? Furthermore the only configuration for auto assign in 5.1 is that SCM in settings right? With only a simple enable option and another tab asking svn username passwords. What are the needed passwords there? Are there any other configuration files? Can you please answer me or direct me in the right path. Thank you very much. Stuck in this for days now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31635645/sonarqube-5-1-core-auto-assign-feature-not-working @agabrys

Comment: Username and password should be used when you have private repository (authentication). I didn't create any configuration files (probably do not exist). Did you install [SCM stats](https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-scm-stats) plugin?

Comment: Yes @agabrys we have scm stats but disabled through its configurations. What can be the possible reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

I am also using SQ 5.1 and Issue Assign plugin works perfectly fine without any issues. You should check your email notification settings.

Comment: In settings -> general -> SCM  is your SCM enabled or disabled?

Comment: Disable the SCM Sensor=Default=False. So SCM is enabled.