# Issue assign plugin in sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube

When configuring issue assign plugin in sonarqube I found examples using the word **key.**

**example** - Key: `sonar.issueassign.default.assignee`

Can you please explain to me how to use this feature and how to use this key to fill the configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [plugin](https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-issue-assign) will assign issue to this user, when can not determine who is the author of change. You should fill it with SonarQube user name.

Example:

```
sonar.issueassign.default.assignee=agabrys
```

Comment: isnt just putting "agabrys" not enough?

Comment: I filled it with SonarQube user name and it worked (changed in SonarQube Web). Currently the plugin is uninstalled (the reasons given in question [Email Notification unpredicted behaviour in sonarqube](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31601557/email-notification-unpredicted-behaviour-in-sonarqube/))