# SonarQube - NullPointerException EmailNotificationChannel.deliver from Issue Assign

Tags: sonarqube

I installed Issue Assigned Plugin (v. 1.6) on Sonar Server (v. 5.1).
When i assinged a issue to an User, the User not receive the Notification.
Perhaps, some users receive the notification and other no.

Look at the logs fro server, a NullPointerException is raise from send notification to this users.

Log:
http://pastebin.com/MskKWjZx

All the users have a login and email.
Anybody know, why some user receive the notifications and other no?

PS: Reports from Sonar Execution are received for all, but Issue Assigned is not received to some users.

Comment: This plugin does not work correctly with SonarQube 5.1. I don't provide answers why you have an error, but I think you should read this topic: [Email Notification unpredicted behaviour in sonarqube](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31601557/email-notification-unpredicted-behaviour-in-sonarqube)

Comment: Thanks agabrys! I will uninstall and wait the new version from Sonar raised..

Answer (score 0):

From the stacktrace you provide, the NPE is raised because a notification has been sent to a username for which no user exist in SQ. Code does not handle this case nicely and throws an NPE because this is not expected.

I don't know the Assigned Plugin but I can only reckon that at least one login which appear in the blame information from your SCM does not have a user configured in SQ and causes this error.

This user might appear quite often in blame results, causes the notification process to fail and prevents sending notification of some of your users.