# Sonarqube 5.1 core auto assign feature not working

Tags: svn, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0, sonarqube5.1

I've heard that issue assign plugin is not needed in sonarqube 5.1 since its built in. But whenever I committed through SVN and run sonar through jenkins all of the team gets an email saying there is an issue but issues are not assigned to the last committer or to anybody.

But when I view the code through sonar I can see it displays the committed persons name in-front of it. Therefore I think that the issue is not with SVN connection or user name identificaiton. (We use same usernames to log in to both SVN and sonarqube)

I've used all the given configurations and the combinations of different configurations. This may not be a valid issue for stack overflow but I would really appreciate any possible help to move forward.

Following are the plugins that i have installed in sonarqube. I just removed SCM Stats plugin
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: How do you build project (Maven, Ant...), how do you run analysis (Sonar Runner, sonar-maven-plugin (post-build action)...)? Can you add logs from build process?

Comment: Using ant. And we run it through jenkins, so "sonar runner. "logs from build process" is unclear to me. can you elaborate? Thanks for the interest @agabrys!

Comment: logs from build process = logs from compilation process (Ant) + Sonar Runner execution

Comment: Please add any comment (e.g. `test comment`) to issue which is not assigned, but should be. Is now assigned?

Comment: I added a test comment to the issue in sonar. But still no assignment. Do I have to rebuild. This is an image of my comment http://i62.tinypic.com/1zmcbiu.png[/IMG]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84348/discussion-between-nilan59-and-agabrys).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue with the directions given in the comments.

By getting the SCM author name (On the left side of Sonarqube code view) and add the exact name as a SCM account.

```
Settings -> Security -> Users -> Edit -> Add SCM account
```